# Simplification of the sum of all 4-digit palindromic numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, palindrome

I apologize for the simplicity of this question, if necessary.

I understand that the sum of all 4-digit palindromes is as follows:
$$\sum_{a=1}^{9}(\sum_{b=0}^{9}abba),$$
which can be further expanded upon such that:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
\sum_{a=1}^{9}(\sum_{b=0}^{9}abba) &= \sum_{a=1}^{9}\sum_{b=0}^{9}(1001a + 110b) \\
                             &= \sum_{a=1}^{9}[10(1001a) + 110\sum_{b=0}^{9}b].
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The last line of the equation is what's confusing me. Where does the $10$ come from in $10(1001a)$?

I don't use double summation notation often, so I assume it has to do with moving the summation of $b$ inside the equation to make the triangular number formula more apparent, but WHY do we need the $10$?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The inner sum is the sum on $b$.  $1001a$ doesn't depend on $b$ so you just get $1001a$ $10$ times.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I was just about to do that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $10$ comes from summing over $b$ from $0$ to $9$. That is,
$$\sum_{b=0}^9 1001 a = 10 (1001 a)$$ so 
$$ \sum_{a=1}^9 \sum_{b=0}^9 1001 a = \sum_{a=1}^9 10 (1001 a)$$

Comment: +1, thank you for the concise and fast answer. That's very simple - @TonyK was right, I confused myself over the variables.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited to add:** Robert Israel's edit has rendered my answer supererogatory, but here it is anyway:

You need to specify the variables in your double summation, because

$$\sum_{a=1}^{9}(\sum_{b=0}^{9}abba)$$

is not the same as

$$\sum_{b=1}^{9}(\sum_{a=0}^{9}abba)$$

You may think the variables are obvious, but this is actually the source of your confusion. We have

$$\sum_{b=0}^{9}1001a = 1001a\sum_{b=0}^{9}1 = 10(1001a)$$

because $1001a$ is independent of $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the wake-up call that I actually need to be clear with my equations! Very simple.

Comment: "supererogatory"... what an interesting word!

Answer (score 1):

The inner sum has an implicit index of $b$.  Making the index explicit yields
$$\sum_{a = 1}^{9}\sum_{b = 0}^{9} (1001a + 110b)$$
Since $1001a$ is a constant with respect to $b$, 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{a = 1}^{9}\left[\sum_{b = 0}^{9} (1001a + 110b)\right] &  = \sum_{a = 1}^{9}\left[\sum_{b = 0}^{9} 1001a + \sum_{b = 0}^{9} 110b\right]\\
& = \sum_{a = 1}^{9}\left[1001a\sum_{b = 0}^{9} 1 + 110\sum_{b = 0}^{9} b\right]\\
& = \sum_{a = 1}^{9}\left[1001a \cdot 10 + 110 \sum_{b = 0}^{9} b\right]
\end{align*}
The factor of $10$ comes from summing $1$ ten times, once for each integer from $0$ to $9$.

Answer (score -1):

The 10 comes from the sum of all the palindromes in one digit. Since there are 10 palindromes for every thousand, that is where they come from.

For Example,

The Palindromes for 1000 is 1001 to 1991, so if we were to find the sum, we have to add all the ones, or multiply it by 10